# What could be the Regex to search strings from a file?

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

I have an HTML file containing these lines -

```
<script>PrintFileURL("13572_BranchInformationReport_2012-06-29.xml","13572_BranchInformationReport_2012-06-29.zip",0,"184277","Jun 29  1:30","/icons/default.gif")</script>
<script>PrintFileURL("13572_BranchInformationReport_2012-07-02.zip","13572_BranchInformationReport_2012-07-02.zip",0,"184302","Jul  2  1:30","/icons/default.gif")</script>
<script>PrintFileURL("13572_IndividualInformationReportDelta_2012-06-29_033352.zip","13572_IndividualInformationReportDelta_2012-06-29_033352.zip",0,"53147","Jun 29  3:33","/icons/default.gif")</script>
<script>PrintFileURL("13572_IndividualInformationReportDelta_2012-07-02_033458.zip","13572_IndividualInformationReportDelta_2012-07-02_033458.zip",0,"62719","Jul  2  3:35","/icons/default.gif")</script>
<script>PrintFileURL("13572_IndividualInformationReport_2012-07-01.acc","13572_IndividualInformationReport_2012-07-01.zip",0,"4033364","Jul  1 12:50","/icons/default.gif")</script>
```

I need to extract the file names from this string -

> 13572_IndividualInformationReportDelta_2012-06-29_033352.zip
>
> 13572_IndividualInformationReportDelta_2012-07-02_033458.zip
>
> 13572_BranchInformationReport_2012-07-02.zip
>
> 13572_BranchInformationReport_2012-07-02.xml
>
> 13572_IndividualInformationReport_2012-07-01.acc

Right now I m using following Regex code -

```
 var fileNames = from Match m in Regex.Matches(pageSource, @"[0-9]+_+[A-Za-z]+_+[0-9]+-+[0-9]+-+[0-9]+\.+(acc|zip|app|xml|def|enr|exm|fpr|pnd|trm)")
                        select m.Value;
```

It is giving me the last 3 files but not the first 2 files.

Can someone provide me one Regex to extract all these files?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `(_+[0-9]+)?` to it:

```
var fileNames = from Match m in Regex.Matches(pageSource, @"[0-9]+_+[A-Za-z]+_+[0-9]+-+[0-9]+-+[0-9]+(_+[0-9]+)?\.+(acc|zip|app|xml|def|enr|exm|fpr|pnd|trm)")
```

That means that it should also match lines with the optional `_+[0-9]+` postfix in filename.

Answer (score 0):

`\d+_\w+_\d+-\d+-\d+(_\d+)?\.+(acc|zip|app|xml|def|enr|exm|fpr|pnd|trm)`

Answer (score 0):

Try the regex below

```
@"^[^\(]*\(\""([^""]+)\"""
```

and use:

```
match.Groups[1];
```